# why this code doesnt pass the logical test

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a python function, create_largest_number(), which accepts a list of numbers and returns the largest number possible by concatenating the list of numbers.
Sample Input =23,34,55
Expected Output= 553423

```
def create_largest_number(number_list):
    number=[]
    for i in number_list:
        while i>0:
            number.append(i%10)
            i=i//10
    number.sort(reverse=True)
    z= ''.join(str(num) for num in number)
    return int(z)

number_list = [23, 45, 67]
largest_number = create_largest_number(number_list)
print(largest_number)[result after submission][1]
```

Comment: Your code splits up all the input numbers into individual digits. I believe the question asks for largest possible *concatenation*, in which the digits of each number have to stay together. So for an input of [71, 56], the answer should be 7156, not 7651.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about your solution but you can try this:

```
def create_largest_number(number_list):
    number_list.sort(reverse=True)
    z= ''.join(str(num) for num in number)
    return int(z)
```